# Responsive circles with messy markup

Tags: html, css

I'm building a feature that has three circles inside of container that are next each other. Initially when I began building this feature I thought that I could just drop my circles into a `flex container` and they would all be good when I added media quires and resized the page.

Much to my despise that was not the case..The circles went inside of the container perfectly but when I started to resize page I noticed that they were squishing! I know this because `border-radius:50%` as circles need to be a percentage and when they are pressed they change there size bc they are fluid.

This issue prompted me to think of solution to prevent the circles from squishing. I had an idea of surrounding `div`s around the circles which would possibly stop them squishing so looked around to see if anyone had done this before.

Much to my liking I found a solution that someone had posted on STO. I modified the solution slightly to meet my own needs which works fine but there's a small issue here, I'm not sure I like the way it makes my markup look. Messy messy messy!

**Solution**

```
 <!-- Projects -->
<div class="circles">
   <div>
       <div>
           <div>
               <div class="projects">
                   <a href="#">Projects</a>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>   
   <!-- About -->
   <div>
       <div>
           <div>
               <div class="about">
                   <a href="#">About</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Contact -->
   <div>
       <div>
           <div>
               <div class="contact">
                   <a href="#">Contact</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Compared to my original markup there is a clear difference in the less amount of `div`s

**Original**

```
  <div class="gridRow">
     <div class="gridItem1">
         <a href="#" id="projects">Projects</a>  
      </div>

     <div class="gridItem2">
        <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
     </div>

     <div class="gridItem3">
        <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
     </div>      
 </div>
```

I'm want to figure a way to clean up the **solution** markup a little more but I'm not really sure if there's a way to do that..I don't want to use svg as I just want a css solution. Any ideas?

Fiddles here

**Squishing circles**
https://jsfiddle.net/kapena/vmt54cd0/

**Responsive Circles**
https://jsfiddle.net/kapena/vmt54cd0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these to the `gridItem` styles:

```
min-width:200px;
width:200px;
max-width:200px;
min-height:200px;
height:200px;
max-height:200px;
```

Comment: works fine! I'll integrate that..Thank you for spotting where I could use `max-width` and `max-height` forgot all about them! Found this cool pen that has a circle that scales here http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/bdMdbK Might also look into incorporating this for all my circles

Comment: You're welcome. Since it's working, you'll want to accept the answer (with the check mark).